# Pandas code is running into memory error with lots of available ram

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn

sklearn fit, MinMax scaler etc run into memory error when I am running the jupyter notebook on ec2-instance of m5a.xlarge (16gb ram). Whereas when I run the same code on my local machine (Macbook air, 8gb RAM), the code runs fine although slowly.

I have checked that my python version is 64bit.

Am I missing something?

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(copy=True)
df2_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df2)
```

this gives following eror:

```py
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

This has been marked possible duplicate of another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866413). Although I get the memory issue even if I run normal .py file. In both cases looking at outcome of 'top' command I can see more than 5gb of free memory

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866413/jupyter-notebook-only-memory-error-same-code-run-in-a-conventional-py-and-wo?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook (only) Memory Error, same code run in a conventional .py and works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866413/jupyter-notebook-only-memory-error-same-code-run-in-a-conventional-py-and-wo)

Comment: I have updated my question with explanation @serafeim

Comment: Your MacBook can use swap. Add the same amount of swap to the EC2 instance and try again.